# Compatibility View and its importance

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have just finished the layout for my website, and it is working perfectly fine in all browsers (Opera, Safari, Chrome, IE 7, 8, 9, 10 (both), and several others) - but this time around, the Compatibility View button in the address bar of IE 10 is appearing. This has not happened for a very long time and it's really annoying me.

I don't want the Compatibility View button to display at all. It sends a bad message to viewers/visitors. In this case, I have tested my whole site on different computers all running different browsers and different versions of browsers and I have not noticed a single problem.

Why is the Compatibility View button appearing if there are no issues?

Here's the problem, and like I said, everything works fine - except for when I turn *ON* Compatibility View in IE 10. When I turn it ON, the only things in my entire website I can see is my logo, and a little image in the top right corner of the page (but they're positioned exactly where I wanted them). What gives?

There's nothing wrong with the code - seriously. i've had it validated several times, all AJAX stuff works like a charm, and I really tried so hard to find a problem and I even intentionally tried to mess it up but it's working really well. The positioning of everything is spot on.

So what's the deal with this Compatibility View junk? Why is it there - on a website that does not have any issues? And, most importantly, *is it important that I make sure my website works well while in Compatibility View even though it works perfectly when it's off and even though it works perfectly in all the major browsers - and then some*?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you tested your site in IE7? Because that's precisely what Compatibility View is (or acts like).

Comment: 100% positive. I even tested in IE6 (it only had minor positioning issues - but they're so minor that I won't even worry about it)! And I even used Dev Tools in IE10 to emulate (if that's the right word) IE7 (as well as using the actual IE7 browser).

Comment: you should check this link http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/internet-explorer/use-compatibility-view#ie=ie-10

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First and foremost, you can force IE not to display the Compatibility View button simply by adding this to your page head:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

As for your other questions:

> Why is the Compatibility View button appearing if there are no issues?

> So what's the deal with this Compatibility View junk? Why is it there - on a website that does not have any issues?

It's there in case a site, typically one that was written many years ago, fails to work in a newer version of IE, to allow users to view or IE to display it in a legacy rendering mode where it will hopefully work better.

Additionally, it's there *by default* because legacy sites will not even have the meta tag above to begin with. In order for the button to display when viewing existing sites without having to update their code, it's only logical to make it an opt-out feature instead, by having the developer add it to new code to tell newer versions of IE to hide the button when it's not needed.

> And, most importantly, *is it important that I make sure my website works well while in Compatibility View even though it works perfectly when it's off and even though it works perfectly in all the major browsers - and then some*?

Compatibility View is meant for websites that were *specifically designed for legacy browsers*, and as such, depend on legacy rendering quirks not present in more recent browsers which may cause "problems" in those more recent browsers.

Without seeing your site, we won't be able to determine why it works in IE7 and IE10 in IE7 mode but not Compatibility View, but if it works well in newer versions of IE, you do *not* need to ensure that it works well in Compatibility View. Using the meta tag above to hide the button when it's not necessary will suffice.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't provide a link to the site. It's my first launch since 2008 and I don't know who it is but when I upload stuff it gets stolen. I know it's necessary but at the moment I really would just settle for tips and known things that (you have provided) would cause issues like this.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide us a link to your site? I always use

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

on the first line of the HTML document. This is a universal switch to the latest rendering mode in all modern browsers. Use BoltClock's solution to hide a compatible view button in IE's address bar. I would prefer a HTTP header rather than HTML meta tag, because the meta tag causes parser switch and reset.

Comment: Although the site is finished, I can't upload it yet. We have people who steal our stuff and I don't want to upload anything until the other related sites are finished. Sorry, I know it doesn't help you help me but I just can't do it. But I do already have `<!doctype html> up the top :-) Thank you